# Animation in Enumerate list - Beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

How do I animate an Itemize or Enumerate List. That is on pressing the enter key, The next Item should appear. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hi
\item Hello
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Whie Herbert has given you one option, here are few more.

**\uncover**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\uncover<1->{\item Hi}
\uncover<2->{\item Hello}
\uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
\uncover<4->{\item Hello again}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**\only**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\only<1->{\item Hi}
\only<2->{\item Hello}
\only<3>{\item Hi again}   %% note absence of - after 3
\only<4->{\item Hello again}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid jumping, you may use `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
\begin{enumerate}
\only<1->{\item Hi}
\only<2->{\item Hello}
\only<3>{\item Hi again}   %% note absence of - after 3
\only<4->{\item Hello again}
\end{enumerate}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**\pause**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hi \pause
\item Hello \pause
\item Hi again \pause
\item Hello again 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want only one item per slide

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item<1> Hi 
\item<2> Hello 
\item<3> Hi again 
\item<4> Hello again
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are these animations automated? Or they work when pressed by a key?

Comment: @subhamsoni They work when you press a key in full screen mode.

Comment: @subhamsoni Yes, they can be done automatically (but this works only in some viewers, typically Acrobat Reader). Please read section **14.3 Slide Transitions** of the `beamer` documentation.

Answer (score 23):

Can be done automatically:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item Hi
\item Hello
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For all lists write into the preamble:

```
 \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

Comment: +1 for the second snippet, really comes in handy sometimes